# Bandwidth Usage in OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, centos, bandwidth, audit

Is there any way to check how much bandwidth a user used in `OpenVPN` (using `PAM` Authentication)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- https://forums.openvpn.net/topic10575.html
- http://openvpn.net/archive/openvpn-users/2007-02/msg00183.html
- http://openvpn.net/archive/openvpn-users/2005-11/msg00258.html
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tunnelblick-discuss/7lGWKR1-rC4
- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.openvpn.user/30934
- https://serverfault.com/questions/459160/how-to-log-openvpn-bandwidth-used

These are some resources which you should be able to apply to do what you want. I found these by just doing a simple Google search for 'openvpn monitor bandwidth'.

Or what about 'openvpn limit bandwidth client', 'openvpn bandwidth usage' or 'openvpn bandwidth limit'...?

**Note**: Would you mind removing that you use `PAM` Authentication from your title and question, since that's off-topic?

**Edit**: Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/465970/limiting-openvpn-bandwidth (there's a good answer from @Zoredache there)